# ¿Como Instalar Git en Kali Linux o Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github, debian

- cuales serian las lineas de codigo que tendria que ejecutar tanto como en Kali Linux ,Como en Ubuntu.
- como saber si tengo instalado git tanto en Ubuntu como en Kali Linux.
  se que los comando son iguales en Kali como en Ubuntu, pero tengo esa pequeña dudad de si varia en algo. la finalidad de esto es poder subir repositorios a GitHub.

Answer (score 7):

Para que la pregunta no quede abierta y sin respuesta. En primer lugar la distribución de `Kali linux` viene por defecto instalado `git` ahora si alguna distribución basada en `debian` no tiene instalado lo más sencillo sería aplicar los comando

```
apt-get update
apt-get install git
```

[más detalles sobre instalación](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Instalando-Git)

> como saber si tengo instalado git tanto en Ubuntu como en Kali Linux.

Lo más sencillo sería verificar la versión de git si tiene instalado le dará como resultado la versión si no le dará un mensaje que no tiene instalado `git`
*(aunque pueden haber muchas más opciones)*

```
git --version
```

Comment: Solo basta actualizar la lista de repositorios para obtener la última versión de cada paquete (`apt update`).

Comment: @GustavoGarcía es verdad , la costumbre de ejecutar los dos comandos a menudo.

Comment: jajaja sí, me pasa igual.

Answer (score 2):

En Distribuciones basadas en Debian, puedes ver la lista de los paquetes instalados por medio del comando `dpkg -l | grep **paquete**` en este caso sería `dpkg -l | grep git`

Answer (score 1):

Revisa que tu distribución no venga ya con git instalado.
Muchas distribuciones enfocadas al desarrollo ya vienen con ella.
Para comprobarlo abre una shell nueva y escribe lo siguiente:

```
git --version
```

Si te da un error puedes instalarlo en Ubuntu con el siguientes comando

```
apt-get update && apt-get install git
```

Para mas información sobre instalación y modos de empleo puedes seguir [esta guía](http://gorkamu.com/2018/08/como-instalar-git/)